# Laravel, querying encrypted data

Tags: laravel, encryption, eloquent

Is there a way in laravel eloquent to query data given the constraint to be a encrypted data?
For example I encrypted all emails I inserted for my Users table, and I want to search it like this

```
User::whereRaw('email LIKE ?', array('%mysite.com'))->get()
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this is not possible with Laravel/MySQL (it would require [homomorphic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption)). You'll need to fetch all rows, decrypt them, and check against their values in PHP.